# How to know the type of a variable in an llvm code

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Is there any method to know the type of the variables in the LLVM code?

For example, I have the following code:

```
%i = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 1, i32* %i, align 4
%n = add i32 6, 1
br label %2
```

And I want a function that returns the type of each of the variables `%i`, `%n` and `%2`, i.e. respectively  `i32*`, `i32` and label
Is there any proposition?

Answer (score 2):

Type* var_type = cur_instruction->getType();

Answer (score 0):

`%i = alloca i32, align 4`, `store i32 1, i32* %i, align 4` and `%n = add i32 6, 1` are *instructions*. You can query their type via their [`getType` method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a0cf3748dba54f931bb1241ae4adc76bc).

`%2` is a basic block and has *label* type. You can check whether a value is a basic block by using [`isa`](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates).